# Adapter.getItem(index) what return value?

Tags: android, listview

As i read `Adapter.getItem(index)` can retreive a data from a ListView. For that reason, i have to use it to make some treatments. The problem is this function returns an object, and in my case i want it to return a String(as my datas are in String). Is there any solution tothis or any alternative ?
Thank you.
Code:

```
AlertDialog alert_reset;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setMessage("Supprimer cette donnee ?")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Oui",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
int id) {
adapter.getItem(arg2);// i want to retreive this
list.remove(arg2);
```

Comment: Post code to show what you have done and what is the exact problem.

Comment: Casting to `String` should work fine. Just out of curiosity, are you calling this piece of code inside `setOnItemClickListener()`?

Comment: @romy_ngo: yes, `setOnItemLongClickListener`

Comment: then `adapterView.getItemAtPosition(int position)` should also work, where `adapterView` is the first argument parsed into `setOnItemLongClickListener`. Remember to cast the result to `String` because it will return with an `Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your Adapter.getItem() to return a String rather than object.

```
@Override
public String getItem(int pos) {
    ....
    ....
}
```

Alternatively, you could cast the Object to type String.

```
String myString = (String) adapter.getItem(arg2);
```